Textures facing inside instead of outside
I'm very inexperienced with Blender. I've only learned enough to place textures on an object and save it as a file that I need for other programs. I have added textures to other 3d objects in Blender with no problem, but this file is giving me issues.
I purchased a 3d file through TurboSquid. All the textures appear to be facing the inside of the object rather than the outside.  I've tried to follow directions on mirroring, recalculating normals, but it doesn't seem to make the texture face the outside.
Would some one mind explaining in layman's terms how to get the textures to face the right way? I would appreciate it so much. Thank you!
The 1st image is what it's supposed to look like, the 2nd image is the top of the object after adding textures, and the 3rd image is the bottom of the object after adding textures.



EDIT: I attempted to subtract Y on all textures as AAA Yerus suggested. Still appears the same.



Can you make a minimal case with e.g. just the front of the fuselage (from the cockpit) or the tip of a wing, and share it using https://blend-exchange.com/ ? Do not forget to pack texture files (see File>External Data). It seems to me that you have some issues with UV mapping between top and bottom...

That's because the texture probably have DirectX format, and Blender operates with OpenGl. The difference between the two is that the 1st one has what is called the 'inverted green channel'. So, to invert it back, do this, and don't forget to use 'non-color' as Texture Space:

Or you can simply export the texture in the OpenGl format, depending on what platform you intend to use it.

Thank you so much for taking the time to respond. I copied what you have there on all the textures and unfortunately it did not change the look. Did I do something wrong, or is there something else I could try? I edited the post with new pictures. Thank you again!
